# C++: Segment fault 11 after performing "push_back"

Tags: c++, debugging, computer-science

PART1

```
typedef long long ll;
struct forloop  {
    char val, lim;
    int dep;
};
vector<forloop> loop;
```

PART2

```
int main()  {

//read
memset(tp, 0, sizeof tp);
loop.clear();
string str;
while (getline(cin, str))  {
    int st = 0;
    while (str[st] <= 32) st ++;
    while (!loop.empty() && loop.back().dep >= st / 4) loop.pop_back();
    if (str[st] == 'f')  { //for loop
        char val, lim;
        string tmp = str.substr(st, 20);
        sscanf(tmp.c_str(), "for %c in range(%c):", &val, &lim);
        **loop.push_back((forloop){val,lim,st/4});**
    }else  { //lag
        doit();
    }
}
out();
return 0;
}
```

After "loop.push_back((forloop){val,lim,st/4});"  I got segmentation fault:11

Does anyone know why? 
Thanks!

Comment: `forloop` and `loop` aren't good names for types or data structures. It doesn't tell me what they represent. `memset` can be a source of errors, but I don't know what is this `tp` you are using it on. `sscanf` can also be a source of errors. Can you use C++ streams instead? You should also consider what should happen if `str` does not contain `st` characters. It could even be empty.

Comment: Your best bet is to go line by line through a debugger.  It's not clear what you're trying to do our what input you're supplying.  I would look at the variable `st`.

Comment: @AnonMail Yes I did line by line debugging and found out that it crashed when it was executing the "push_back". Thanks anyway!

Comment: Did that occur on the first `push_back`?  After 1 million `getline`s?  Also, this `(forloop){val,lim,st/4}` looks odd to me.

Answer (score 0):

If the call to push_back is causing the problem, then you might out of memory because you've pushed back too many elements. Count the number of elements there are in the vector to see that you haven't accidentally created way too many.

I'm wondering what you meant by "after" in your comment at the end. Do you mean it might be happening in the doit() function?